# Microsoft Azure Program like BizSpark

Tags: azure

Microsoft used to have a program called BizSpark that offered $100k free azure usage.  Do you know if they now have an equivalent that I could use and how I could get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [doc](https://portal.startups.microsoft.com/about/faq), you should use [Microsoft for Startups](https://startups.microsoft.com/en-us/) now.

Some information from the [doc](https://portal.startups.microsoft.com/about/faq):

**In February 2018, BizSpark was replaced by the [Microsoft for Startups](https://startups.microsoft.com/en-us/) program.**

**We are no longer accepting new startups into the BizSpark program. Please see [Microsoft for Startups](https://startups.microsoft.com/en-us/) to learn about our current startup offering.**

Hope it helps.